# Create distribution of available values - Python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I'm hoping to create a **distribution** that displays the times an employee is available to work. Similar to this figure, which is found at this link [staff distribution](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/01/employee-scheduling-i-matlab-vs-gams.html).

[image: Matrix Distribution]

To achieve this, I've created the `staff_availability_df` that contains the number of employees to pick from, which is found in the `['Person']` column. The `min - max` hours they can work, how much they get paid are labelled as such. The available times they can work are separated into hours `['Availability_Hr']`, which  represents the times they can work expressed in hours. So the first person is `'8-18'`, which is `8:00:00am - 18:00:00pm`. The `['Availability_15min_Seg']` is essentially the same but hours are split up into 4 segments. So the first person is `'1-41'`, which is again `8:00:00am - 18:00:00pm`.

Note:  The standard shift operates between `8:00:00am - 3:30:00am`, so approx 20 hours.

The `staff_requirements_df` displays the `Time` throughout the shift and the required `People` I need.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates

#This is the employee availability:
staff_availability = pd.DataFrame({
    'Person' : ['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5','C6','C7','C8','C9','C10','C11'],                 
    'MinHours' : [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],    
    'MaxHours' : [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10],                 
    'HourlyWage' : [26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26,26],  
    'Availability_Hr' : ['8-18','8-18','8-18','9-18','9-18','9-18','12-1','12-1','17-3','17-3','17-3'],                              
    'Availability_15min_Seg' : ['1-41','1-41','1-41','5-41','5-41','5-41','17-69','17-69','37-79','37-79','37-79'],                              
    }) 

#These are the staffing requirements:
staffing_requirements = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : ['0/1/1900 8:00:00','0/1/1900 9:59:00','0/1/1900 10:00:00','0/1/1900 12:29:00','0/1/1900 12:30:00','0/1/1900 13:00:00','0/1/1900 13:02:00','0/1/1900 13:15:00','0/1/1900 13:20:00','0/1/1900 18:10:00','0/1/1900 18:15:00','0/1/1900 18:20:00','0/1/1900 18:25:00','0/1/1900 18:45:00','0/1/1900 18:50:00','0/1/1900 19:05:00','0/1/1900 19:07:00','0/1/1900 21:57:00','0/1/1900 22:00:00','0/1/1900 22:30:00','0/1/1900 22:35:00','1/1/1900 3:00:00','1/1/1900 3:05:00','1/1/1900 3:20:00','1/1/1900 3:25:00'],                 
    'People' : [1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,3,3,4,4,3,3,2,2,3,3,4,4,3,3,2,2,1],                      
     })
```

I have exported the staffing requirements in 15min segments that occur between `8:00:00am - 3:30:00am` using the following functions. Each 15min is assigned to the `string` `'T'`. So `T1 = 8:00:00am` and `T79 = 3:00:00am`

```
staffing_requirements['Time'] = ['/'.join([str(int(x.split('/')[0])+1)] + x.split('/')[1:]) for x in staffing_requirements['Time']]
staffing_requirements['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(staffing_requirements['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
formatter = dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 

staffing_requirements = staffing_requirements.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15T',key='Time'))['People'].max().ffill()
staffing_requirements = staffing_requirements.reset_index(level=['Time'])

staffing_requirements.insert(2, 'T', range(1, 1 + len(staffing_requirements)))
staffing_requirements['T'] = 'T' + staffing_requirements['T'].astype(str)

st_req = staffing_requirements['People'].tolist()

[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0]
```

I'm hoping to use these functions to create a `linear programming matrix` that returns a **distribution** of the times each employee is available to work. But I'm hoping to use 15min segments as well as hours. e.g. Note: This export will extend to `3:30am`. So it will contain 79 segments.

Note: To be clear. I'm hoping to return the distribution schedule so it can be used for a future purpose. Not just a figure.

[image]

There are a few staff availability [example 1](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/01/employee-scheduling-i-matlab-vs-gams.html) [example 2](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/01/06/generating-an-optimal-employee-work-schedule-using-integer-linear-programming/) approaches using `mixed-integer linear programming` but they use closed source software. I'm hoping to translate this to Python.

Comment: get the total of workable hours  (total_people / total_hours) . then between this range you distribute people and make sure someone does not work twice??

Comment: The Hungarian Algorithm would not work for this. You have too many variables for it to handle.

Comment: Thanks @Yay295. What if I simplified the input variables to 1. That being, it a person has to work between 5-10 hours. Or would the problem still not be appropriate?

Comment: See [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/01/employee-scheduling-i-matlab-vs-gams.html) (and references in that post) for some ideas.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, thanks. That link is helpful. I've done some research on this. Most of the issues I've seen face a linear approach to staffing requirements. As in, 1 or 2 staff begin, it then builds to a peak and then declines. My specific problem is a bit more complex as the requirements vary throughout the day. Staff requirements peak and trough randomly, which creates various paths to determining shift times. That link did provide some alternative approaches though

Comment: I think the MIP models I pointed to can handle any demand pattern (assuming time is appropriately discretized). Demand is just data for these models.

Comment: Ok. The distribution of recording demand did change my thinking. Thanks. I'll see how I go

Comment: What is the optimization function? Or are all possible solutions equivalent?

Comment: Do you need to make an actual timetable? Or do you just want to print "a distribution that displays the times an employee is available to work like shown" -- i.e. essentially print out your raw data? The question is unclear on what you need.

Comment: I assume you down voted. I hoping to return an actual timetable sorry. I'll re-adjust the question. I thought a figure would represent the question more effectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a great job for integer programming; you could use `pulp`, which you would first need to install via the command line, e.g. `pip install pulp`

## Data manipulation to set ourselves up for success

Then, first make sure your `DataFrames` are in optimal shape so we can attack the problem:

```
# Since timeslots for staffing start counting at 1, also make the
# DataFrame index start counting at 1
staffing_requirements.index = range(1, len(staffing_requirements) + 1) 
print(staffing_requirements.tail())

staff_availability.set_index('Person')

staff_costs = staff_availability.set_index('Person')[['MinHours', 'MaxHours', 'HourlyWage']]
availability = staff_availability.set_index('Person')[['Availability_15min_Seg']]
availability[['first_15min', 'last_15min']] =  availability['Availability_15min_Seg'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int)

availability_per_member =  [pd.DataFrame(1, columns=[idx], index=range(row['first_15min'], row['last_15min']+1))
 for idx, row in availability.iterrows()]

availability_per_member = pd.concat(availability_per_member, axis='columns').fillna(0).astype(int).stack()
availability_per_member.index.names = ['Timeslot', 'Person']
availability_per_member = (availability_per_member.to_frame()
                            .join(staff_costs[['HourlyWage']])
                            .rename(columns={0: 'Available'}))
```

where `availability_per_member` is now a `MultiIndex DataFrame`that has one row per person per timeslot, indicating his/her availability and wage:

```
#                 Available  HourlyWage
#Timeslot Person                       
#1        C1              1          26
#         C2              1          26
#         C3              1          26
#         C4              0          26
#         C5              0          26
```

Additionally, we change the requisites a bit so the problem is actually solvable; see the appendix for why this is necessary

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
staffing_requirements['People'] = np.random.randint(1, 4, size=len(staffing_requirements))
staff_costs['MinHours'] = 3
```

## Solve the Integer Programming problem with `pulp`

Now, we can get pulp to work: set up the problem with the goal of minimizing the costs, and adding the constraints you mentioned one-by-one, see the commented code. `staffed` is now a pulp-dictionary containing whether a person is staffed at a certain time slot (either 0 or 1)

```
import pulp
prob = pulp.LpProblem('CreateStaffing', pulp.LpMinimize) # Minimize costs

timeslots = staffing_requirements.index
persons = availability_per_member.index.levels[1]

# A member is either staffed or is not at a certain timeslot
staffed = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("staffed",
                                   ((timeslot, staffmember) for timeslot, staffmember 
                                    in availability_per_member.index),
                                     lowBound=0,
                                     cat='Binary')

# Objective = cost (= sum of hourly wages)                              
prob += pulp.lpSum(
    [staffed[timeslot, staffmember] * availability_per_member.loc[(timeslot, staffmember), 'HourlyWage'] 
    for timeslot, staffmember in availability_per_member.index]
)

# Staff the right number of people
for timeslot in timeslots:
    prob += (sum([staffed[(timeslot, person)] for person in persons]) 
    == staffing_requirements.loc[timeslot, 'People'])


# Do not staff unavailable persons
for timeslot in timeslots:
    for person in persons:
        if availability_per_member.loc[(timeslot, person), 'Available'] == 0:
            prob += staffed[timeslot, person] == 0

# Do not underemploy people
for person in persons:
    prob += (sum([staffed[(timeslot, person)] for timeslot in timeslots])
    >= staff_costs.loc[person, 'MinHours']*4) # timeslot is 15 minutes => 4 timeslots = hour

# Do not overemploy people
for person in persons:
    prob += (sum([staffed[(timeslot, person)] for timeslot in timeslots])
    <= staff_costs.loc[person, 'MaxHours']*4) # timeslot is 15 minutes => 4 timeslots = hour
```

And then, it's a matter of letting `pulp` solve the case:

```
prob.solve()
print(pulp.LpStatus[prob.status])

output = []
for timeslot, staffmember in staffed:
    var_output = {
        'Timeslot': timeslot,
        'Staffmember': staffmember,
        'Staffed': staffed[(timeslot, staffmember)].varValue,
    }
    output.append(var_output)
output_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(output)#.sort_values(['timeslot', 'staffmember'])
output_df.set_index(['Timeslot', 'Staffmember'], inplace=True)
if pulp.LpStatus[prob.status] == 'Optimal':
    print(output_df)
```

This will now return a DataFrame `output_df` which per timeslot and person contains whether they are staffed:

```
#                      Staffed
#Timeslot Staffmember         
#1        C1               1.0
#         C2               1.0
#         C3               1.0
#         C4               0.0
#         C5               0.0
#         C6               0.0
#         C7               0.0
#         C8               0.0
#         C9               0.0
#         C10              0.0
#         C11              0.0
#2        C1               1.0
#         C2               1.0
```

I've adapted the code of http://benalexkeen.com/linear-programming-with-python-and-pulp-part-5/ which is a great tutorial to pulp and linear programming, so be sure to check it out.

## Appendix: your requirements are infeasible.

With your conditions, this will actually return `'Infeasible'`. It's easy to see why this is:
[image: Required staff vs available staff]
You can see there are more staff members required than available in the last few timeslots. This plot was created by:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
staffing_requirements.plot(y='People', ax=ax, label='Required', drawstyle='steps-mid')
availability_per_member.groupby(level='Timeslot')['Available'].sum().plot(ax=ax, 
                               label='Available', drawstyle='steps-mid')
plt.legend()
```

Comment: This is brilliant attempt @Jondiedoop. I reduced the scope of the question as I thought it was too large for a single post. Your `availability_per_member` can be used to a make a distribution of available times of employees. I have tried a few conditions to solve the shift schedule but it always returns `Infeasible`. Can you post which conditions it worked for you?

Comment: I can remove the `HourlyWage` becomes this is identical for all employees.

Comment: Happy to hear it helped you. It works e.g. when you (before the part that starts with importing pulp), you change the conditions to `import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42); staffing_requirements['People'] = np.random.randint(1, 4, size=len(staffing_requirements)); staff_costs['MinHours'] = 3;` I'm afraid I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to adjust the constraints but can't seem to produce an output.

Comment: @jonboy I just added more information about why the original problem was unsolvable

Comment: Thanks. This was an oversight on my behalf. I had a play with the constraints and got an output when I lowered the `MinHours` to `3`. I'm assuming it will to say unfeasible if it can't achieve an output that fits the constraints perfectly. As in, there isn't any _slack_. Also, when I did lower the `MinHours` to see the output, the first 8 times lots were: `C2, C2, C1, C3, C6, C1, C5, C2`. Your code will no doubt fast track the shift schedule significantly!

Comment: I also checked the function using the dummy data. I had a similar output with `T1 = C1, C2, C3`. `T2 = C1`. `T3 = C1, C2, C3`. `T4 = C1, C2, C3`. `T5 = C6`. `T6 = C5`

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, a [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) could work. Pick an option that increases your optimization function the most etc; if no options available for the next step, backtrack and pick the next best option, etc.

As explained on the link, how optimal the found solution would be depends highly on the kind of the optimization function.