# How to implement 2D interval scheduling in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I have a problem that is similar to the conventional interval scheduling algorithm but it's two dimensional, so I have another metric (length) to take into account. My dataset format:

- Cars with the start and end time of parking, along with their length
  in meters.
- Total street length in meters (500m)
- Number of cars
- Opening hours of street parking (2-22)
  --> Start and end times are in whole hours and length in whole meters.

I was thinking of splitting the street up into short 1 meter segments, but that wouldn't ensure a best solution as I wouldn't be able to optimize the locations based on later segments.

Objective: The goal is to fit all cars in the street parking (Assumed possible). Output will be the location of the car during the given time period.
The goal is similar to this post: [Create distribution of available values - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330016/create-distribution-of-available-values-python), but the length has to taken into account: a car can't be split up.

This can be seen in the following figure (car IDs filled in):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGeDV.png)

(I figured out this might be a linear programming or multi-objective optimization problem?)